# Tornado websockets did not receive messages in browser until second connection

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, tornado

I want to enhance [Lightweight Django example](https://github.com/lightweightdjango/examples/tree/chapter-8/scrum) to send some periodical updates using PeriodicCallback, with usage of redis and tornado-redis, but now without Django (for first steps).

I wrote some code (the minimal example with ommited cleanup of unused callbacks):

```
class MyHandler(WebSocketHandler):

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def open(self, user):
        self.sprint = user
        self.uid = uuid.uuid4().hex
        self.application.add_subscriber(self.sprint, self)

    def on_message(self, message):
        c = PeriodicCallback(lambda: self.application.broadcast("test", channel=self.sprint, sender=self), 1000)
        c.start()
```

When I start tornado app, connect from developer console:

```
(
function(){ ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/1/");

    ws.addEventListener('open', function(e){ console.log('open', e);  
    ws.send('test'); });

    ws.addEventListener('message', function(e){console.log('msg', e.data)}); }
)();
```

At first time, it sends message to server, server answers (at least it calls app.broadcast), but I cant see any output in browser: it says socket is open, it does not show any error when I define onerror function, it does not show that socket closes when I define onclose.

When I type in console the same function again, browser start receiving messages.

Comment: Probably error is in add_subscriber or broadcast methods. Can you add them to your question?

Comment: @Fian https://github.com/lightweightdjango/examples/blob/chapter-8/scrum/watercooler.py#L144